# Java Application Development for BlackBerry® smartphone with Eclipse Galileo

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I would like to start with BlackBerry Devolopment.

Is to possible to start devolopment with Ubuntu?

How to install Java Application Development for BlackBerry smartphone with Eclipse Galileo in Ubuntu? (Searched over but, all says to installation with Eclipse Helios)

Please connect me with useful beginners tutorials...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately BlackBerry Eclipse Plugin is only supported under Win and Mac.

You may be able to get the Java SDK going in Ubuntu, but the simulator is only supported in Win. For Mac, you need a device to be tethered for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

[BlackBerry Development Using Linux](http://www.slashdev.ca/2008/04/03/blackberry-development-using-linux/)

google-fu is your friend  ;)
as he mentions, it is not ideal, but it works.